# CRUD operations using Mongosheet

Tags: mongodb, google-sheets

I am trying to use Mongosheets (an addon for Google Sheets which lets you perform crud operations on your mlab databases)

For this to work, we need to provide it with the API key and enable data access API as shown in the figure. and then it works like a charm.

[image]

The issue here is that my DB is on an ubuntu ec2 instance and I don't know how to generate an API key and use 
Mongosheets with my DB on ec2.

Any help or even alternatives for the same will be appreciated.